# Angular4 are arrays reference types

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an HTTP service which returns some JSON and I subscribe to observable, then assign the result to two arrays:

```
selectedData: any[];
selectedList: any[];

private get() {
    this.dataService
        .Get()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.selectedData = data;
            this.selectedList = data;
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

now every time I change on the dropdown, I have the same object for both:

```
onChange(selectedValue) {
    console.log(this.selectedData);
    console.log(this.selectedList);
    this.selectedData["exercisesProgress"] = this.selectedData["exercisesProgress"].filter(x=>x.id == selectedValue);
}
```

aka selectedData and selectedList are both filtered when I check in the console. Is this same reference or? Do I have to create a new instance of selectedList and push data to selectedList instead of directly assigning?

Comment: _Is this same reference_.. yes. You could use `Array.prototype.slice()` to get shallow copies of the array.

Comment: can you check my answer, is that viable way from performance perspective?

Comment: it depends on what you want really. 1. `Object.assign()` will make a shallow copy and give an _object_ instead of an array. `this.selectedData.slice(0)` would give you a shallow copy of array. 2. You would have to use other libraries/means to get a deep copy if thats what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with copying objects with Object.assign({}, data):

```
private get() {
    this.dataService
        .Get()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.selectedData = data;
            this.selectedList = Object.assign({}, data);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
}

onChange(selectedValue) {
    console.log(this.selectedData);
    console.log(this.selectedList);
    this.selectedData = Object.assign({}, this.selectedList);
    this.selectedData["exercisesProgress"] = this.selectedData["exercisesProgress"].filter(x=>x.id == selectedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *destructuring* when you initialize the values for `selectedData` and `selectedList`. That will make the two arrays separate from each other right from the start, and you will not have to worry about it after that point.

```
private get() {
  this.dataService.Get()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.selectedData = [...data]; // <=======
      this.selectedList = [...data]; // <=======
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: can this be used only on arrays? because I made a mistake and this.selecteData should not be an array,just object

Comment: @AmelSalibasic for an `Object`, you can use `this.selectedData = Object.assign({}, data);`. If `data` is an `Object`..

Comment: @AmelSalibasic then maaaybe an upvote would be nice :)